# Android JavascriptInterface problem

Tags: android, user-interface, webview, textview

I am an Android beginner. I am trying to change a textview value in an activity in a webview javascript call to javascript interface class. There is a webview and a textview in the activity layout.

**MyWebActivity**

```
public class MyWebActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String url =  "http://myurl...";
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.loadUrl(url);

        webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(this), "Android");
    }
    ...
}
```

**JsInterface.java**

```
public class JsInterface {
        ...
       public void setUIText()
       {
             TextView textView1  = (TextView) ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            /*This line not work*/
        textView1.setText("Hello"); 

            /*This line work*/  
            Toast.makeText(mContext, textView1.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
}
```

**the html file**

```
Android.setUIText();
```

Then problem is, when I call `Android.setUIText()` in the html file, it trigger the JsInterface's setUIText, and I cannot set the text for the `textView1`, but I can get the textView1's text using `getText()`.

What's the reason? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you get any error? Try debugging your code.

Comment: You should probably be getting your pages from https:// url, since untrusted pages with malicious javascript could hack your device - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415882

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this.
javascript interface run in a new thread (not in the main). 
So, to change your UI (the textfield owned by `MyWebActivity`), you need to use an handler to re-Synchronize events.

step:

1. create an handler in your `MyWebActicity`.
2. In javascript interface in the method that should change your textfield send an empty message to your MyWebActivity. (ex: `hrefresh.sendEmptMessage(MyHandler.REFRESH_TEXTFIELD)`).
3. manage the empty message in your handler, that will call a method in your `MyWebActivity` that will change the textfield

Answer (score 2):

Just add these lines in your **setUIText** Function

```
      public void setUIText()
      {
           final String msgeToast = toast + newToast;           
           myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   // This gets executed on the UI thread so it can safely modify Views
                   myTextView.setText(msgeToast);
               }
           });
           Toast.makeText(mContext, textView1.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
final TextView textView1  = (TextView) ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.textView1);
((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView1.setText("Hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
myTextView.post(...
```

as well.