# How to WebView.getTitle() from a UI thread?

Tags: android, android-webview

In a subclass of `WebView`, I used to have this line in an overridden method of `getTitle()`:

```
String title = super.getTitle();
```

It worked well in all versions of **Android**, until I got to test my app on an **Android 4.1** phone, which gave me this warning on that `super.getTitle()` line:

> 12-20 21:38:27.467: W/webview_proxy(2537): java.lang.Throwable:
>   Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'WebViewCoreThread'.
>   **All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread.** Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.

So, I was thinking of working around this new decree by passing it through `runOnUiThread()`:

```
Activity a = this.getActivity();
a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() { 
    String title = super.getTitle();
    }
});
```

But this code won't even compile because `super` no longer refers to `WebView`, but rather to `Activity`.

Any idea how How to `super.getTitle()` from the UI thread? (with the constraints described above, in the `getTitle()` of a subclass of `WebView`)

Comment: **Where** is the snippet you show with `Activity a = ...` being placed?  Are you placing it in the overridden `getTitle()` method of your `MyWebView` class?

Comment: Actually, `super` in the anonymous `Runnable` class above points to `Object` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Morgan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14112894/119114), while it may fix the compile error, is not really a solution to this problem.

First of all, it does nothing to change the call to `getTitle()` to a different thread.  That underlying issue is why Android is giving you the error at runtime.

You say in a comment that

> The circumstances are that I am calling it in WebViewClient.onPageFinished(), which happens not to be on the UI thread.

That *may* be a problem.  If you are starting the web request from the UI thread, then `onPageFinished()` should certainly get called back on the UI thread.  Can you explain how you are starting the web request, and *why* you're doing it that way? The vast majority of the time, you shouldn't be seeing `onPageFinished()` called in the background, so you may have a problem elsewhere.

(Note: if you think you need to call `WebView.loadUrl()` in the background to avoid blocking the UI, please [see this other answer on that issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11259703/119114))

**If** you really think you need to start the web request in the background, and you see `onPageFinished()` called in the background, you need to take care to call `getTitle()` on the UI thread.

Also, if you are calling it from the `onPageFinished()` method, then there is no need to use syntax like this:

```
String title = MyWebView.this.getTitle();
```

in that method, you are passed the instance of your web view, so just use it directly:

```
public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
    String title = view.getTitle();
}
```

but, as I said, that doesn't address the threading issue.  You would need to show us **why** you are trying to use the page title in that method, but *one way* to safely use it would be something like this:

```
public void onPageFinished (final WebView view, String url) {
   view.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() { 
         String title = view.getTitle();
         // do something with title that affects the UI here
      }
   });     
}
```

**Note** that I needed to make the `view` parameter `final` in the above code.

Comment: +1 for a remarkably educational answer but... I ***do*** loadUrl() from the UI thread! So why does `onPageFinished()` get called on a non-UI thread?

Comment: First of all, I would double/triple check that it's really getting called on the background.  Put a breakpoint in `onPageFinished()` and stop there in the debugger, and look at the Debug pane to see that some thread other than Thread-1 is calling the method.  If it isn't the main/UI thread, can you show us the code that calls `loadUrl()`?  Also, are you implementing `WebViewClient` just to get the `onPageFinished()` callback, or are you doing other things in your `WebViewClient` implementation?  Adding that code to your question above could help, too.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll also add that my last code snippet, that uses `view.post()`, should solve the problem, even if `onPageFinished()` **is** getting called in the background.  However, I think it would be better to figure out *why* this is happening.  As such, that solution is still a *workaround*.

Comment: Ouch! You're right. I made a mistake: onPageStarted & onPageFinished both get called on the UI thread. It's a `JavascriptInterface` method (called in onPageFinished via `view.loadUrl`) that's on another thread. It's been a while since I looked at the code... my apologies for not being accurate from the start. As for your other question, I am only implementing `WebViewClient` to do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5172952/1088880). The correct solution is probably to `view.post()` the `view.loadUrl()` so that it runs on the UI thread, right?

Comment: No worries.  So, no `runOnUiThread()` or `view.post()` is needed in `onPageFinished()`.  But, I would still write the code per my middle code snippet (`String title = view.getTitle();`) as using `MyWebView.this.getTitle()` is really unnecessarily complex, and less robust, in this situation.  Also, you apparently still have a problem with what you're doing in your `JavascriptInterface` method.  So, probably **that method** should use `post(Runnable)` or `runOnUiThread(Runnable)`.  See [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6758604/119114)

Comment: I have to re-accept & give *you* the bonus, because I love your answer for its desire to stick to [correct practices](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10558238/1088880) and fixing the *root cause* of problem instead of working around symptoms. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  Yeah, if you are using `runOnUiThread()` or `post()` because you're in a JavaScript interface method, then that's not a hack, but a proper solution.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a direct answer to your question but I can suggest a workaround that worked for me when I encountered a similar problem: Find the method that calls the method that calls `String title = super.getTitle();` and run **it** via [runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

HTH.

Comment: Thanks (+1) but I am still interested in accessing MyWebView's super + its data members.

Comment: Turns out your solution was the correct one from the start, but it didn't provide the explanation *why*, like @Nate explained.

Answer (score 2):

The direct solution is to do this

```
String title = MyWebView.this.getTitle();
```

instead of

```
String title = super.getTitle();
```

That being said, it would be interesting to know more about the circumstances under which you are calling this (I.e., why you are calling it in the background).  I ask because I am not sure that your approach will do what you want even after you make the code change I mentioned.

Comment: Or even `MyWebView.getTitle()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I think you would get "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getTitle()" in this case.

Comment: @Morgan, thanks. I will try your solution and report back. Answering your question: The circumstances are that I am calling it in [WebViewClient.onPageFinished()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29), which happens **not** to be on the UI thread. Additional insights?

Comment: Interesting -- that actually surprises me a little. In any case, you should be good to go with MyWebView.this.getTitle().  Good luck!

Comment: @Morgan Why does it surprise you? BTW, your solution `MyWebView.super.getTitle();` works! I now need to understand why? (i.e. the syntax `Classname.super` is not clear to me). Thanks (+1) & accepting.

Comment: I think it surprised me because it sounds like a UI-ish callback,and often those kinds of callbacks are on the UI thread so that client code (like yours) can take main thread actions easily.

Comment: I will try to find the java language spec for this feature.  Think of it this way -- there are two "this" objects in your code's context: the "local" this (the anonymous Runnable subclass) and the "parent" this, your MyWebView.  Think of the syntax MyWebView.this as just a way of telling the JRE which one you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this warning, you do the following:

```
  Handler handler =new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String URL = "http://www.superlinux.net";

            //Of course the object "webview" is a WebView. 
            //it's better to define it a global variable
            webview.loadUrl(URL);
        }
    });
```

Therefore, using this way, because webview is UI element, you use a Handler object. Handlers are some kind of threads that runs separately from the creation any UI element.