# how to display javascript popup in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, popup

Is it possible to open a javascript popup window on a android webviewer coded like this example from google? and if yes how?
I dont want that the original page in the background is closed it has to be a popup like on the picture.

[Building Web Apps link](http://developer.and)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

See answers to this question:

[JavaScript alert not working in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271898/javascript-alert-not-working-in-android-webview)

The answer from Stephen Quan is to just set the default webChromeClient

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can allow javascript and opening windows from javascript in a webview. Just set this settings

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

Be careful though because enabling javascript on your app webview can bring some serious security issues

check this links

[From StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736660/android-app-using-webview-javascript-what-can-be-security-concern)

[Interesting Presentacion](http://www.acsac.org/2011/openconf/modules/request.php?module=oc_program&action=view.php&a=&id=111&type=3&OPENCONF=f7f97640d21493db2a3bbea529027855)

and this one for webviews

[Official Android WebView Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Comment: I tried that already but it's not working. Do i need special permissions or something like that?

Comment: you do need to add this permission but not javascript related <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: If you want to run native javascript code, you better check this official android link about web views [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) Start reading where it says "Enabling Javascript in WebView"

Comment: And one more thing, the link in your post is broken